# Jasmine-karma error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

The **app running fine** with `"@angular/core": "5.0.3"` and `"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3"`, while run unit test, getting error on the karma debug page.

At first time got the below error message,

error :

`no provider for Storage`

next added :

`import { IonicStorageModule, Storage } from '@ionic/storage';`

to .spec.ts file and added to provider as well then getting different error message called

`Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)`.

How can I solve this issue from spec.ts file / any internal file changes require ?

**login.component.spec.ts** :

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { IonicModule, Platform, NavController} from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from "../../otherts/login.service";
import { GlobalLoginSession } from "../../otherts/GlobalLoginSession";
import { IonicStorageModule, Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

describe('Login Component', () => {
  let de: DebugElement;
  let comp: LoginPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPage>;
  let a : boolean;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginPage],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(LoginPage)        
      ],
      providers: [
        NavController,
        LoginService,
        GlobalLoginSession,
        IonicStorageModule,
        Storage
      ]
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h3'));
  });

  it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());

});
```

**login.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Events, IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import { LoginService } from "../../otherts/login.service";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
//import {TabsControllerPage} from "../tabs-controller/tabs-controller";
import {MyApp} from "../../app/app.component";
import {GlobalLoginSession} from "../../otherts/GlobalLoginSession";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
    public rawJsonData: any ;

    disableEmail : false;
    myform: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myform = new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
            loginAsMobile: new FormControl(),
            email: new FormControl(),
            mobile: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
            password: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
        });
    }

    public submitIt() {
        console.log("Submitting  assuming the form is valid.......");
        let firstName = this.myform./*get('name').*/get('firstName').value;
        let lastName = this.myform./*get('name').*/get('lastName').value;
        let loginId : any;
        let loginTypeMobile = this.myform.get('loginAsMobile').value;
        let password = this.myform.get('password').value;
        if(loginTypeMobile)
        {
            loginId = this.myform.get('mobile').value;
        }else{
            loginId = this.myform.get('email').value;
        }

        this._loginService.doLogin( { loginId:loginId, password: password}).subscribe(data => {
            console.log("formSubmitted:",data);
            this.rawJsonData  = data;
            if ( this.rawJsonData && this.rawJsonData.status == "$200") {

                this.loginSession.isPatient = this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.isPatient ;
                this.loginSession.subID =        this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.accountId ;
                this.loginSession.patientId = this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.memberId ;

                this.loginSession.h5cAuthToken = this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.h5cAuthToken ;

                this.loginSession.needChangePassword = <boolean> this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.chngPswd ;
                this.loginSession.needChangeProfile = <boolean> this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.profUpdate ;

                this.loginSession.message = this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.message ;
                this.loginSession.loginId = loginId;
                this.loginSession.isMobileLoginId = loginTypeMobile;
                this.loginSession.firstName = firstName;
                this.loginSession.lastName = lastName;
                this.loginSession.message = this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.message;

                this.loginSession.sessionActive =  true ;

                if( this.loginSession.isPatient) {
                    console.log("You are a patient you are allowed to login into this app");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("You are not a patient still, you are allowed to login into this app, you will ejected out soon");
                }

                console.log("Login Message",this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.message);

                this.storage.set("authToken", this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.h5cAuthToken);
                this.storage.set("memberId", this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.accountId);
                this.storage.set("patientId", this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.memberId);
                this.storage.set("loginId", loginId);
                this.storage.set("loginTypeMobile",loginTypeMobile);
                this.storage.set("firstName", firstName);
                this.storage.set("lastName", lastName);

                console.log("loginId "+loginId);

                //this.navCtrl.push(TabsControllerPage);
            }else{
                alert(this.rawJsonData.httpHeaders.message);
            }
        },(err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    constructor(public _loginService:LoginService, public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage,private events:Events, private loginSession : GlobalLoginSession) {
    }
    add(num){
        return num + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the spec code, and the code for the component you are trying to test?

Comment: @R.Richards - added

Comment: And what about the code for the component you are trying to test?

Comment: @R.Richards - added the ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `IonicStorageModule`, not add it in providers:

```
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(LoginPage),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

(as explained in [docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage))

You also don't need anything else in providers, since the IonicStorageModule would likely export the `Storage` provider you want to use

```
  providers: [
    NavController,
    LoginService,
    GlobalLoginSession
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks Dolha - runs fine now !